# find a record by date sql Server

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, datetime

I've a table product(prodID,stock,createdDate type DATETIME )

Wanna find all record from table for the current date

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to build a `WHERE` clause against the `createdDate` column in your `SELECT` statement.  Have you tried doing that?  Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rounds to the current date:

```
...
WHERE createdDate >= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

- `GetDate` returns the current datetime
- `datediff(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0)` returns the days from the first date until now
- `dateadd(dd` ads ... these days to the first date, so we get the current date without time

Comment: it work , Thank you vm, What if I want to find all record for date X?

Comment: @Myaw: `WHERE createdDate BETWEEN dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @startDate), 0) AND dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @endDate), 0)`

Comment: this query to find all records between two date so what If I want show all records for @date  = X ?